# Response code: 400 Bad request/Error Message: No Ids were specified

Tags: api, restsharp

I am trying to send Get request using RestSharp but getting this message in response:Bad Request/
**{"Message":"P1001: No Ids were specified"}**. Could someone help please to figure out that? Seems like it's not adding Parameter list to the Request Body...

Here is my code:

```
    public partial class DTO
    {
        public List<string> evidenceIds { get; set; }
    }

    public RestRequest GetPlayRequest(Method requestType, string token)
    {
        DTO MyObject = new DTO();
        MyObject.evidenceIds = new List<string>();
        MyObject.evidenceIds.Add("6F00CAE1-F16E-47F6-AF3F-D10305DD7859");
        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject);
        var restRequest = new RestRequest(requestType);
        restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        restRequest.AddParameter("text/json", jsonString, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        restRequest.AddHeader("Organization", "Bofa");
        restRequest.AddHeader("Username", "Admin");
        restRequest.AddParameter("Authorization", "Bearer " + token, ParameterType.HttpHeader);
        return restRequest;
    }
```

[The request with all params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBULh.png)

[The Content response after sending the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgCRJ.png)

Comment: I'd suggest sending yu request to a request bin (https://requestbin.com). You can then check what the request body looks like. If you add the request content to your question, I think I'll be able to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Hi @AlexeyZimarev, Thank you for your attention! I am attaching two screenshots in here: 1. The request with all params and 2. The Content response after sending the request. 

I added the pictures above to my question. I would appreciate any help/suggestion!

Comment: Sorry, but request parameters don't really tell you how the actual request would look like. When you use something like requestbin.com, you can see exactly how your request looks like, and compare it with what the server expects.

Comment: HI Alex, never mind. I ended up upgrading Restsharp from 105 to 107 and it solved the problem. Seems like some issues were with the old library version

Comment: That's good to hear. The code posted in my answer is for RS 107.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexeyZimarev!

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following:

```
public RestRequest GetPlayRequest(Method method, string token)
{
    var obj = new DTO { evidenceIds = new string[] 
        {"6F00CAE1-F16E-47F6-AF3F-D10305DD7859" }
    };
    return new RestRequest(method)
        .AddJsonBody(obj)
        .AddHeader("Organization", "Bofa")
        .AddHeader("Username", "Admin");
        .AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
}
```